# Show bottom tab bagge according screen info

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

What I need is to show a badge according to some info located in a screen tab, this is what I have:

```js
export const ProductsScreenLogic = ({ navigation }) => {
  const products = [{ id: '1' }];

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      tabBarBadge: products.length,
      title: 'Products requested',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4',
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: '#000000',
        fontSize: 24,
      },
      headerTitleAlign: 'left',
    });
  }, [navigation, tours.length]);

  return <ProductsScreenLayout products={products} />;
};
```

Works as expected, when the user goes to the tab that renders the screen the badge is displayed. What I want is that this badge is always visible, not only when the screen is rendered/focused. I can achieve this by placing the `tabBarBadge` option in the screen like so: `<MyNavigator.Screen options={{tabBarBadge: tours.length}}/>`, but I would not have access to the component data, `products` in this case.

How could I always render the badge no matter if the screen is focused and also be able to access the screen state?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement this by decoupling `products` from your UI logic. This could be done using a `Context` or an application cache encapsulated inside a custom hook.

Here is the first solution using the `Context` API. First, I have created a file called `AppContext` containing the following content.

```js
import React from 'react';

export const AppContext = React.createContext({
  products: [{}],
  setProducts: () => {},
});
```

Then, create the context value in form of a state and add the `ContextProvider` in the root application. I have added an effect that performs some initial data fetching. I have just added some values for this demo.

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState();
  const appContextValue = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      products,
      setProducts,
    }),
    [products]
  );

  // initial data fetching (backend call.. whatever)
  // I just set a value here for demonstration
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setProducts([{id: '1'}, {id: '2'}])
  }, [])

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <AppContext.Provider value={appContextValue}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="ScreenA" component={ScreenA} options={{tabBarBadge: appContextValue.products?.length}} />
            <Tab.Screen name="ScreenB" component={ScreenB} />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

You are now able to always show the `tabBarBadge` and additionally access this state in any other screen. For example, we can access it in `ScreenB` as follows.

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { AppContext } from './AppContext';
export function ScreenB() {
  const {products, setProducts} = React.useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>ScreenB!</Text>
      <Text>Product Count: {products?.length}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[Here is a little snack for this implementation](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/tab-navigation-%7C-react-navigation).

However, the above solution might not be ideal in all use cases, especially when fetching data from some remote API. Thus, I have implemented a second solution using [SWR hooks](https://swr.vercel.app/).

First, I have implemented a custom hook called `useProducts`. It contains the following code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import useSWR from 'swr'

export function useProducts() {
  
  const { data, error, mutate } = useSWR('/api/products', () => {
    // your backend call must be implemented in here.
    // I just add some dummy data for this demo.

    return [{id: '1'}, {id: '2'}]
  })

  const refresh = React.useCallback(() => {
    mutate()
  }, [mutate])

  return {
    products: data,
    error,
    refresh
  };
}
```

Notice, that the above is specifically designed for caching data from an API.

We use it as usual.

```js
import { useProducts } from './useProducts'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {

  const {products} = useProducts();

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen
            name="ScreenA"
            component={ScreenA}
            options={{ tabBarBadge: products?.length }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen name="ScreenB" component={ScreenB} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Or in any other screen, e.g. `ScreenB`.

```js
import { useProducts } from './useProducts'

export function ScreenB() {
  const {products} = useProducts();

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>ScreenB!</Text>
      <Text>Product Count: {products?.length}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[Here is a snack for the above version](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/swrhooks).